# MySQL Queries only grabbing one row from table

Tags: php, mysql

The following code seems to be only grabbing one row of information in the array when I want it to grab the entire column.

```
$id = null;
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//declare variables
$countr = null;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `convert`";
$drippage = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // <-- that quote; change members to whatever the table is 
//this counts the number of rows
if (mysqli_num_rows($drippage)) {
    $countr = mysqli_num_rows($drippage);
}
$ToAndFrom = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ToAndFrom FROM `convert`");

$ToAndFromR = mysqli_fetch_array($ToAndFrom, MYSQLI_BOTH);

$Formula = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Formula FROM `convert`");
$FormulaR = mysqli_fetch_array($Formula, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to implement that as a loop  while( $FormulaR=mysqli_fetch_array($Formula, MYSQLI_BOTH)) { /* do something usefull with results */ }

Comment: Then use a `while` loop for fetching the array. Querying `_num_rows` is redundant, in particular when doing it twice, and without using the result.